# compact returns data without accents

Tags: laravel, dompdf

when I send with compact what is obtained in a variable, in the blade the accents are seen with 0 and /

It has utf8 in the database, and html, the strange thing is that the same data is seen well from a foreign view.

The query is as follows:

```
$query=
malformacion_paciente::whereIn
('malformacion_pacientes.nombremalformacion_id', $request->mff)
      ->LEFTJOIN('mal_formaciones AS mf', 
      'malformacion_pacientes.nombremalformacion_id', '=', 'mf.id_nombremalformacion')
      ->LEFTJOIN('formaciones AS f', 
      'f.id', '=', 'mf.formacione_id')
      ->LEFTJOIN('nombremalformacions AS nm', 
      'nm.id', '=', 'mf.id_nombremalformacion')
      ->get();

      $enfermedades = $query->countBy(function ($item) {
        return $item[('descripcion')];
      });




      $malfomarcion = $query->countBy(function ($item) {
          return $item['name'];
        });
```

Where I send the variable `$diseases` and it returns the following

[image]

When trying to send it to the PDF that I generate with DOMPDF, it throws me the following:

[image]

As I mentioned, I have utf8 in the database and html, so the query goes well, but it arrives without the accents, and I can't remove the .json output

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with the next:
go to config/database.php file and change your charset and collation as

'charset' => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJj5H.png)

or you can use utf8_encode() method